# want to open same form from 2 button but every buttoncan openform once

Tags: c#

I have form  to  show Customer and  vendors  if  I open form from  button1 the forms Show  customer and if I open from button 2  form  show vendor

the problem here I wanna the buttons open form 1 time for each  I made  this code but the first it work for the first opened form only and the another button open many time as much as I click the button

```
if (Application.OpenForms[frm.Name] != null)
                    {
                        if (Application.OpenForms[frm.Name].Text == e.Item.Caption)
                        {
                            frm = Application.OpenForms[frm.Name];
                            frm.BringToFront();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            frm.Show();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        frm.Show();
```

Comment: Maybe keep track of opened forms in a List. Add form name to list when its opened, and remove form from list when it closes. Check list before opening new form.

Comment: I just reread your post. Since you open each form from 2 different buttons, another option is, when you open a form, disable the button. When the form closes, reenable the button. You would want to pass the button to the constructor of the opened form, and in the onClose event of the opened form, reenable the button.

Comment: @David.Warwick good trick   but what is wrong  with my code ?

Comment: I cannot tell what is wrong with your code. I need to see more code than what you have posted. I need more information. But I think the simplest idea would be to disable the button when the form opens, and reenable the button when it closes. I will post some sample code below. Stand by.

Comment: Sounds to me like you should just store a single instance of the form in the button's tag and then cycle it's visibility when the button is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I modified my code to get open  forms text and add  them to string and checked if the string contain the caption of button it wont  open it for second time
here is my code ,thanks for David.Warwick  he  give  me the idea where i need  to  start

```
if (Application.OpenForms[frm.Name] != null)
                    {
                        var texts = "";
                        foreach (Form fr in Application.OpenForms)
                        {
                            texts += fr.Text +  "/";
                        }
                            if (texts.Contains(e.Item.Caption.ToString()))
                            {
                                frm = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Where(x =>  x.Text  == e.Item.Caption.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();;
                                frm.BringToFront();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                frm.Show();
                            }
                        
                    }
                    else
                        frm.Show();
```

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is the code for the form that contains the buttons. I just called it Form1.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btnCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnCustomer.Enabled = false;

    CustomerVendorForm form = new CustomerVendorForm(btnCustomer);
    form.Show();
}

private void btnVendor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnVendor.Enabled = false;

    CustomerVendorForm form = new CustomerVendorForm(btnVendor);
    form.Show();
}
```

And here is the CustomerVendor form:

```
public partial class CustomerVendorForm : Form
{

Button Form1Button;

public CustomerVendorForm(Button button)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Form1Button = button;
}

private void CustomerVendorForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Form1Button.Enabled = true;
}
```

So we disable the button that they clicked. Open the form, passing the button. When the user closes the form, the button is re-enabled.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor:

```
btnVendor.Tag = new VendorForm();
btnCustomer.Tag = new CustomerForm();
```

In your button click handler (you only need one - this code will handle any number of different buttons and forms)

```
anyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  ((sender as Control).Tag as Form).Visible ^= true;
}
```

--

So, your Tag is in use by some Thing already? OK, probably the easiest thing is to is make a class to hold all the things you want to put in the Tag:

```
class TagBucket{
  public Form SomeForm { get; set; }
  public Whatever OtherThing { get; set; } //you don't have to set this now, just demonstrating 
}
```

In your constructor:

```
btnVendor.Tag = new TagBucket {
  SomeForm = new VendorForm(),
  OtherThing = new Whatever()
};

btnCustomer.Tag = new TagBucket {
  SomeForm = new CustomerForm(),
  OtherThing = new Whatever()
};
```

In your click handler:

```
anyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  ((sender as Control).Tag as TagBucket).SomeForm.Visible ^= true;
}
```

Comment: in my case i cant use your code cuz i use Tag  for other things

Comment: If you need to store multiple things in a Tag you do the same thing you would do anywhere else in an OO program; make a class to store them. For example if you want to store a string firstname, a string lastname and an int age, you make a class Person with those 3 properties. You can make some class to hold all the things on your Tag in exactly the same way. I made an edit to demonstrate

Comment: but my 2  buttons open same form to  do different thing from each button  in your  case every button open  another form

Comment: and any way , i done it with some modification and posted it as answer ,  it work great and done  exactly what  i want , but your code added new to my knowledge  ,thank you

Comment: So, put the same form in then! Your question was not very detailed; I'm showing the technique, but you have to apply the variation to make it suit your situation..